# How to solve error: "undefined is null or not object ie in ext js" in IE?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I think its the cause of trailing comma, or syntax error, variable used without declaration. My js fiel is 1000 lines od code. Since the error is not provding me the line no. Its becoming dfficult to debug. Please help me with debugging techniques for IE. The script works very well with Firefox, Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) the file. That will find the issue as well as any others you may have.

You can run it as a [command line utility via node](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/).

Comment: I had tried the online jslint but it gave me too amny errors but I think jslint can be useful. I will go through it. Gd for validation.

Comment: Did you set the options? With defaults options it is very aggressive.

Comment: @wombleton I will discuss with you elaborately later.So that you can help you out.

Comment: Yes, I had set options like tolerate html fragemnts,assume as a browser, etc. It gave errors for eg: not to declare array as new Array() but as literals etc and not giving errors which stopped execution for time being but they are good to follow but I want to have a release yesterday.So, want to debugg faster.It also says Problem at line 436 character 9: Stopping. (20% scanned). So I later I thought to put certail lenght of blocks of code and check for errors. Thats help the problem to solve.

Comment: "It will be better if it jslint has option for "show strict syntax errors" which help us to know what is stopping from execution. Later, you can follow gd to follow syntax."

Answer (score 4):

include this `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>` and `<html debug="true">` will give you an firebug console
http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Debug

Comment: FirebugLite can also be added after page load, using a bookmarklet.

Comment: FYI, Firebug 1.4 doesn't work in IE8, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532909/firebug-lite-messagequeue-null

Answer (score 1):

For debugging in IE I would recommend you install [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/). This extension is similar to FireBug for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing through *Microsoft Visual Studio* I remember it will help you find trailing commas by highlighting the following `}` element with a green curly underline.

If you use the built-in *developer tools* in *IE8* and later, you can step through your code in the browser and determine which line causes the error - starting from the top.

If you are not using any debugging tools in *IE*, then I will advise you to - just like **Johan** and **bjornd** are suggesting.

Happy hunting :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse :

configure [spket](http://spket.com/download.html) plug-in editor for java script

It will highlight the missing/incomplete syntax (e.g comma/semicolon)

so you don't need to debug for syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Guys, I finally did it ? I took the strength of all your techniques.

1) I put the code in a single 
try{
code
}
 and catch(e) {
    alert('Final Err: '+ e.description);
}

and kept initial 200 lines uncommented and the rest commented and ran the file

```
while(EOF) {
  if(got an alert of error)
    checked for trailing commas & putting missed semicolons till end.
  else
     adding some more lines later uncommented out of the commented and ran the file.
}
```

> Finally, the page got succesfully loaded !!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using the Extjs RowExpander user extension.  The issue only occurred in IE.  I was able to fix it by adding a few lines of code at the top of the 'toggleRow' method:

```
if (!this.view) {
    this.bindView();
}
```

For some reason IE occasionally chokes on references to 'this.view' (likely a timing issue).  Running 'bindview()' ensures that 'this.view' resolves appropriately.